# Rails Model Association Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

I am building a app(to learn rails) which allows companies/(individuals too) to create a profile page to list their employees and skills so a user to my site able to find people based on the skill so he/she can hire them as a contract employee for a period of time.

I have these models company,employee,skill,contract but i am confused about how to make associations between these models to do what i want.

Is there any open source projects similar to this exist so i can learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employeeskills
  has_many :skills, :through => :employeeskills
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :contracts
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employeeskills
  has_many :employees, :through => :employeeskills
end

class Employeeskill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :skill
end

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contracts
end
```

Then you can ask for `@user.contracts` or `@employee.skills` etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any open source projects to look at but have you been through the [Getting Started Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)? It covers basic associations.

Comment: odin, Thanks I read it already but I am confused about how to associate the models I have than Association in general :)